# EPSG code for UTM zone

Tags: coordinate-system, utm

Using python I want to convert coordinates from one spatial reference system to another. I usually use the osgeo library for this which works very well. I have however come to the situation that I need to convert to a UTM zone further away from the equator (say UTM zone 29U for example). For this zone I can not find an EPSG code on spatialreference.org.

Why is it that I can only find codes for zone either north or south of the equator (29N and 29S)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The UTM zones and their respective EPSG codes cover the whole area of their respecive zone from the equator to 84N / 80S. These areas are subdivided by the letters from South to North, and these again are subdivided into 100km grid squares, but the projection system is not affected by these subdivisions. Hence for 29U you can use EPSG:32629.

For areas above 84N / below 80S you should use the Universal Polar Stereographic coordinate system.

Answer (score 8):

The latitude band is, strictly speaking, an MGRS thing, not a UTM thing. For UTM, all you need to know is which side of the equator you’re on, so for 29U, you can use EPSG:32629.